# The data type is DT_NTEXT, which is not supported with ANSI files

Tags: sql-server, export

Trying to export a table to a flat file by using Tasks / Export Data menu.

I am trying to export to ANSI 1252 Code Page.

My table has some `nvarchar` columns in it.

I am getting the message:

> The data type is DT_NTEXT .... which is not supported with ANSI files ... Use DT_TEXT instead and convert the data to DT_NTEXT using the data conversion component.

I have tried changing the source column mappings in the Columns Mapping section from Unicode string `DT_WSTR` to just string `DT_STR`, it didn't work.

Is it possible to export to ANSI file without altering my table? Is there an easier way? I couldn't find a way to change the source columns to regular `varchar` string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to use the **Data Conversion Component** to convert the data if you cannot change your source columns.

Changing the source columns that is the easiest but not always an option. For example, I am returning a delimited list using `XML FOR PATH` and since I am doing this in a stored procedure, all I needed to do was convert the column to `varchar(max)` and the error went away and SSIS was happy.

```
select distinct 
    [WhatIfId],
      cast(stuff
        (
            (
                select 
                    '; ' + plr.[Label] 
                from [dbo].[track_rate_override_reasons_instance] tor
                join [dbo].[PickList_Loans_WhatIf_Rate_OverrideTypes] plt
                    on plt.[OverrideTypeId] = tor.[OverrideTypeId]
                join [dbo].[PickList_Loans_WhatIf_Rate_OverrideReasons] plr
                    on plr.[ReasonId] = tor.[ReasonId]
                FOR XML PATH ('')
            )
            , 1, 1, '') as varchar(max))  AS 'OverrideReasons'
from [dbo].[track_rate_override_reasons_instance]
```

Is it possible for you to wrap your source within a stored procedure so that you can manipulate the conversion?

Comment: What is the data conversion component?

Comment: Is the data conversion component possible to use with SQL Server Management Studio's Export Wizard?  I found changing my SQL query as you suggest to work best in my case.

Comment: Everywhere I go researching this problem, I find stuff saying to use the Data Conversion Component, but I can't find anything explaining WHAT the Data Conversion Component is, nor how to get to it. This is very frustrating!

Comment: On the last couple of steps, before you complete the wizard, you can save your setup work to a file.  Use the location where you save that file and load using SSIS.  You can then work on the issues using the integration services offered by SQL Server.  Look for "Save SSIS Package" on the Save and Run Package Section.  Avoid encryption issues by placing the protection level as "Do not save sensitive data"  Either File System or SQL Server is fine, but you'll have a physical touch if you use the file system.  SQL Server means you have to find it under Integration Services.

Answer (score 100):

For anyone looking for an alternative solution;

- Edit your Flat File Connection Manager
- In General tab
- Tick 'Unicode', OK

This solved the above problem for me.

Comment: This solved the problem for me too, was try to move data from MSSQL to Postgres

Comment: Where is this "Edit your FLat File Connection Manager"? I'm using SSMS and have the same problem (it complains I can't export a nvarchar(max) field to a Flat File)

Comment: @BjornW when you run the import/export wizard, when you choose "Flat Source..." and then the file, you'll see it under the browse, checkbox Unicode. (Have to choose a file first, otherwise it's greyed out) Hope that helps, I had to check it to get my nvarchar(max) to export...

Comment: In addition, set the Code page to 65001 (UTF-8) via the dropdown https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/215816

Comment: is there any other way to solve this issue... I'm continuously getting this error in many of my tables and I cant change the datatypes... I did all the things as per the suggestions @KScandrett

Comment: There is no "Flat File Connection Manager", It is the "Choose a Destination" page. Below the Browse button is a checkbox labeled Unicode. Check it to support NVARCHAR columns. The Code Page selection will be grayed out.

Answer (score 4):

For record, I faced similar issue today. Shuffling the data types between DT_TEXT, DT_NTEXT, DT_WSTR, DT_STR, nothing worked with both ANSI and UNICODE format combinations. Understood the issue was with source field that was of a data type varchar(max) - not sure why we assigned this data type. Change it to nvarchar(50) and the export worked without any issues and without any need to change the data type in export wizard.

Comment: I had a table with nvarchar(max). And received an error "The data type is DT_NTEXT .... which is not supported with ANSI files ... Use DT_TEXT instead and convert the data to DT_NTEXT using the data conversion component."  Changed nvarchar(max) to nvarchar(80), exported it as a csv file. Worked as a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Having worked with SQL Server and SQL Server Integration Services, the suggested method works but can be infinitely less troublesome if you use a Python import script, assuming you are running Python.

```
import numpy as np
# csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
import sys
import csv
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dtype=np.int64

data1 = pd.read_csv (r'<path>\<file>.csv', sep='\\t',  engine='python', encoding = \utf-16\) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

params =  urllib.parse.quote_plus(\DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MyMachineName\\MyInstance;DATABASE=MyDBName;Trusted_Connection=yes;\)
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine = create_engine(conn_str)

# create the table
df2.to_sql(\MyTableName\, engine)
```

It may require an update or a download and definitely requires a target database server.